# Jersey error with @PathParam

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I'm using Jersey and I have following two RESTful methods:

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public List<Activity> getAllActivities() {
    return activityRepository.findAllActivities();
}
```

and

```
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@PathParam("{activityId}")
public Activity getActivity(@PathParam("activityId") String activityId) {
    return activityRepository.findActivity(activityId);
}
```

Everything worked well before I added the second method. However, my tomcat now gives the following error.

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by @Consumes and @Produces annotations
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `@Path("{activityId}")` instead of `@PathParam("{activityId}")`

Documentation states that

@PathParam

> Binds the value of a URI template parameter or a path segment containing the template parameter to a resource method parameter, resource class field, or resource class bean property.

@Path

> Identifies the URI path that a resource class or class method will serve requests for.

Thus, `@Path` should be used to define URI path that resource method will serve.